# venn diagram category help.

Tags: discrete-mathematics

For each list of categories, draw a venn diagram that shows the relationship among the categories. One of the categories describe the universal set, and the others describe the various loops inside the universal set.

1. Water vessels, submarines, war boats, sailboats, battleships, ferries
2. Old cows, dairy cows, cows, cows wearing bells.

Note: I am having trouble categorizing these two questions, especially the 2nd one. I can't figure out the relationships among them. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: What "3rd one"? You quoted only 2 questions.

Answer (score 0):

HINT: Submarines, war boats, sailboats, battleships, ferries are all water vessels. So water vessels is the universal set. We can consider submarines and battleships as war boats. So they are subsets of war boats. But you cannot be a battleship and a submarine at the same time. So they are actually disjoint subsets. Can you follow the reasoning on wards?

EDIT: Okay, so Old cows, dairy cows, cows wearing bells are all cows. So cows is the universal set. And note that they are all strict subsets, since there are young cows, non-diary cows, and cows that do not wear bells. At this point we can only proceed with a few assumptions.

For example we can assume that young cows don't produce milk, so they can't be diary cows. In that case, diary cows becomes a strict subset of old cows. Since any kind of cow can wear a bell, the set of cows wearing bells intersects with set of diary cows and the set of old cows.

We could also proceed without the above assumption, and get old cows, diary cows, and cows wearing bells to be mutually intersecting strict subsets of cows.

Comment: I need more help with the 2nd one.